# How to use a control like the one in Visual Studio's Class Details window

Tags: .net, listview, treeview, controls, custom-controls

There is a control in Visual Studio's Class Details window (accessed via Class Diagram) which combines a ListView with a TreeView.  The result looks something like this:

```
TreeViewNode1
  Column 1      Column 2       Column 3
  Column 1      Column 2       Column 3
TreeViewNode2
  Column 1      Column 2       Column 3
  Column 1      Column 2       Column 3
```

All of the TreeView Nodes are collapsable so that you can view only the nodes you want to.  I am looking to implement this, but it doesn't seem to be a .net control.  Does anyone know of a control which already exists that allows this?  It has to be free (as in beer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/treelistview.aspx

Found source code here.  It's in C#, so had to build a DLL first then include it in my project.

Answer (score 1):

The [ObjectListView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView.aspx) project has a TreeListView:

[image]
<sub>(source: [codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/KB/list/ObjectListView/TreeListView.png))</sub>